# Error while Run or Debug using pycharm GUI but ok when I run using pycharm terminal

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, pytest

Case 1 : No Error
If I run using pycharm terminal using the below command it is running successfully.
pytest -v -s testCases/test_login.py

Case 2 : Error
But when I run or debug using using Pycharm GUI options, i 'm getting below error.

I have tried setting Path and Pythonpath variables under system and user environment variables.

collecting ... ERROR: not found: C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\nopCommerce\testCases\test_login.py::Test_001_Login::test_homePageTitle
(no name 'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\nopCommerce\testCases\test_login.py::Test_001_Login::test_homePageTitle' in any of [])

[image]

[image]

Run/Debug Configuration:
[image]

Comment: Did you configure `pytest` as the test runner in your project (under Settings/Tools/Python Integrated Tools)? It looks like it tried to use `unittest`.

Comment: Setting looks as -> Default test runner : Autodetect(pytest) ,  Attached the snapshot above.

Comment: Can you check that the run configuration (e.g. "Python tests for test_login...") indeed uses pytest?

Comment: I have attached snapshot of Run Configuration , is there anything I need to change ?